# Why the loss function (mse) calculated by keras not the same as mine

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I want to test the loss function, mse in keras by myself. However, the calculated answers are different. The definition of mse is below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error

The test code is below:

```py
from keras.datasets import boston_housing
import numpy as np
(train_data, train_targets), (test_data, test_targets) = boston_housing.load_data()


x_train = train_data.astype(np.float32)

from keras import models 
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential() 
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(13,))) 
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')) 
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

y_train = train_targets.astype(np.float32)
# y_test = test_targets.astype(np.float32)

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=1,batch_size=404)

print(np.mean((y_train - model.predict(x_train).ravel()) ** 2))
```

It shows that the loss function is around 816 in keras. However, from the definition of mse, the results is around 704. Why are the results different here?

Comment: suppose you change your `epochs=1,batch_size=404` i.e. train the complete batch in one go, so you are not giving the model much training, and model training gave you mse. Now with that trained model, you predicted your same training data. the model will not give you the same mse, as when it saw your 404 data points it has adjusted the weight. So it will be very unlikely that the model does the same performance on train data, otherwise it will be an over-fitted model.

Comment: @simpleApp I have changed the epochs and batch_size, still the loss function results are not the same. For keras, it is 8412. For my calculation, it is around 1469. Thanks

Comment: they are far apart so not making sense. need to dig more.

Answer (score 0):

You did the mean of the differences of the squares, you need to do the mean first on the matrix and then on the list of samples, you didn't do the mean in the numpy arrays, you need to do the difference one sample at the time, not on the list of samples.

Here's the implementattion of mse:

```
def my_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.mean(np.square(y_pred - y_true))
```

Do this FOR EACH sample one at the time and then do the mean

Comment: thanks for the reply. It's a good idea to set customized mse loss function in keras. However, I am still not fully understand the process in keras. What do you mean I need to do the mean first on the matrix and then on the list of samples? Can you show the revised code so that the results can be the same? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I have not found that the tensor of the output of model.predict(x_train) is 2. I have revised the code and reduce the tensor to 1. Hope your further suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

the code you have used is actually doing matrix subtraction, try this code to calculate mse error:

```
sub_sqr=0
for a,b in zip(y_train,model.predict(x_train)):
    sub_sqr+= (a-b)**2

print(f"rme : {sub_sqr/len(y_train)}")
```

if you increase your epochs and optimize the model, your mse will be almost same otherwise some difference would be expected.

with this  `model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=4000,batch_size=404)`

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 7.3889 - mse: 7.3889
```

```
rme : [7.54777]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have revised the code. The model.predict(x_train) is a matrix, this reason this difference above is mistakenly calculated as a matrix. The model.predict(x_train) has been converted to array. Can I ask why the results only match when the epoch is large? If the batch_size is 404, each epoch means the parameters (weight and bias) are updated once. I use the model.predict(x_train) to obtain the predicted y value. Then using the formula: np.mean((y_train - model.predict(x_train).ravel()) ** 2) to obtain the mse function. It should be the same as the results calculated from keras.

Comment: large epoch - want to train the model for large repetition so it overfits training data. usually in production, your objective would never be this, as your approach would be to reduce mse on data that the model never observed/seen(aka testing data). Also training the model is different than functional coding, you want to tune your model for high prediction success and that is why you have put reLU there. make sense?

Comment: As for the model above, if the epoch is one, then the parameters will be updated for one time. After the update of the parameters, we should get the mse under current parameters using the code: print(np.mean((y_train - model.predict(x_train).ravel()) ** 2)). It should be equal to the loss calculated from keras. Why is it related to epoch? Epoch should only affect the times of the parameters updated, right?

Answer (score 0):

## epoch =1

```
from keras.datasets import boston_housing
import numpy as np


##################### set random seed. ########################
# Seed value
# Apparently you may use different seed values at each stage
seed_value= 0
# 1. Set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)
# 2. Set the `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import random
random.seed(seed_value)
# 3. Set the `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed_value)
# 4. Set the `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
# for later versions: 
# tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(seed_value)
##################### set random seed. ########################

(train_data, train_targets), (test_data, test_targets) = boston_housing.load_data()


x_train = train_data.astype(np.float32)

from keras import models 
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential() 
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(13,))) 
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')) 
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
y_train = train_targets.astype(np.float32)
#get values before training
y_pred1=model.predict(x_train)
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=1,batch_size=404)
print(np.mean((y_train - model.predict(x_train).ravel()) ** 2))

#model.trainable=True
#get values after training 
y_pred2= model.predict(x_train)#batch_size default setting be 32 
#get values after training 
y_pred3= model.predict(x_train,batch_size=404)
#get values after training 
y_pred4= model.predict(x_train,batch_size=100)

print(np.mean((y_train -y_pred1.ravel()) ** 2))
print(np.mean((y_train -y_pred2.ravel()) ** 2))
print(np.mean((y_train -y_pred3.ravel()) ** 2))
print(np.mean((y_train -y_pred4.ravel()) ** 2))
```

the result in my machine is
[enter image description here][1]

## epoch = 2

```
from keras.datasets import boston_housing
import numpy as np

##################### set random seed. ########################
# Seed value
# Apparently you may use different seed values at each stage
seed_value= 0
# 1. Set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)
# 2. Set the `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import random
random.seed(seed_value)
# 3. Set the `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed_value)
# 4. Set the `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
# for later versions: 
# tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(seed_value)
##################### set random seed. ########################


(train_data, train_targets), (test_data, test_targets) = boston_housing.load_data()


x_train = train_data.astype(np.float32)

from keras import models 
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential() 
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(13,))) 
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')) 
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
y_train = train_targets.astype(np.float32)
#get values before training
y_pred1=model.predict(x_train)
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=2,batch_size=404)
print(np.mean((y_train - model.predict(x_train).ravel()) ** 2))

#model.trainable=True
#get values after training 
y_pred2= model.predict(x_train)#batch_size default setting be 32 
#get values after training 
y_pred3= model.predict(x_train,batch_size=404)
#get values after training 
y_pred4= model.predict(x_train,batch_size=100)

print(np.mean((y_train -y_pred1.ravel()) ** 2))
print(np.mean((y_train -y_pred2.ravel()) ** 2))
print(np.mean((y_train -y_pred3.ravel()) ** 2))
print(np.mean((y_train -y_pred4.ravel()) ** 2))
```

if epoch=1000, you will find the mse of keras and self implemented MSE will output same value, because the model is well trained,the weight of model will not change

In a word ,the output of keras is always one epoch later than we expected